# No such file or directory with NodeJS and NodeMailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I'm training NodeJS developing a registration system with tokens and authentication, in the password recovery part, using nodemailer I have this problem.

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/src/resourses/mail/src/resourses/mail/password.handlebars'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/src/resourses/mail/src/resourses/mail/password.handlebars'
}
```

Here is the `mailer.js`:

I'm taking hos, port, user, pass, from a json file, which contains this data

```
var transport = mailer.createTransport({
    host,
    port,
    auth: {
        user,
        pass
    }
});

transport.use('compile', mailerhbs({
    viewEngine: {
        partialsDir: "src/resourses/mail/",
        extName: '.handlebars'
    },
    viewPath: path.resolve('src/resourses/mail/'),
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
}));
```

And here is the call to send the email, in the authController:

```
mailer.sendMail ({
             to: email,
             from: 'marlorodrigues@outlook.com.br',
             template: 'src/resourses/mail/password',
             context: {token}
         }, (err) => {
             if (err) {
                 console.log (err);
                 return res.status (400) .send ({error: "Couldn't send email"});
             }

             return res.send ();
         });
```

But there is this file, I tried .html, .handlebars, but it still didn't work, I searched a lot on the internet, but I didn't find anyone with this problem, I hope you can help me, thanks ....

https://github.com/marlorodrigues/cadastroNodejs

Comment: If you look at the file it can't find you see a double specification of `/src/resourses/mail`.  That means you're passing that in too many places.  I don't know this specific library setup, but I would guess that you have it both in the `partialsDir` and in the `template` specification and thus the engine combines these two and you get a duplicate.  I would suggest changing the template specification to be just the filename `template: 'password'` and see if that either works or changes the structure of the path in the error. Post back if it works or show us the new error you get if it doesn't.

Comment: Try to read '/src/resourses/mail/src/resourses/mail/password.handlebars' this file with the fs(File System) module if you are still getting this error, So the path of specified file must be wrong.